# MAX group by date returns MIN value - SQL

Tags: sql, max, min

Simple set of data:

```
B1_PER_ID3  Course Type  Course Expiry Date
00AW2      Life and A&S  04/30/2020
00AW2      Life and A&S  02/22/2021
```

View:

```
select
    B1_PER_ID3,
    [Course Type],
    max([Course Expiry Date])
FROM V_ICOBC_COURSE_PIVOT   
group by B1_PER_ID3, [Course Type]
having B1_PER_ID3 = '00AW2'
```

returns for this record. Other records mostly look fine:

```
B1_PER_ID3  Course Type   MaxDate
00AW2      Life and A&S   04/30/2020
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any other `where` or `having` filters?Any other joins or applys? What DBMS is this, if it's SQL Server what is the server collation, and what is the collation of `B1_PER_ID3`?

Comment: It is SQL server.

I figured this out. The dates are originally stored in a text field. Some may have something not right stored there.
I added CAST as date around dates and it works now properly.

thank you everyone.

Comment: You can self answer rather than answering in a comment.